# Use column values from one subarray as keys for anotheer subarray's values

Tags: php, arrays, array-column, array-combine

I have an object as below,

```
{"metaData":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}],"rows":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}
```

I would like to change it to

```
[["a"=>1,"b"=>2],["a"=>4,"b"=>5],["a"=>5,"b"=>6]]
```

Is there any faster one liner that can convert this without going thru a loop in Laravel ?

Comment: Faster than _what_? Show us the code you've written. And by "faster", do you actually mean "faster to execute", or "uses fewer characters of source code", or "easier to read"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the keys with `array_column`, then map `array_combine` over the rows.

```
$keys = array_column($object->metaData, 'name');
$result = array_map(fn($row) => array_combine($keys, $row), $object->rows);
```

You could make it a one-liner like this, but it's more difficult to read, and it will call `array_column` for every row instead of just once.

```
$result = array_map(fn($row) => array_combine(array_column($object->metaData, 'name'), $row), $object->rows);
```

You need to be sure that each row is the same size as the metadata array or `array_combine` will fail. Based on the appearance of your object, it looks like this would probably always be true, but it's important to note.

Comment: Additional versions of the same advice: [with `array_walk()`](https://3v4l.org/MckGs) and [with `foreach()`](https://3v4l.org/NS5vt)